# How to display pdf content in web page using html5 and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

How to display **pdf** document inside my **div**. I am using **HTML5** and [jquery](http://jquery.com/) to build my mobile site. I need to display my pdf document inside a [**Turnjs**](http://www.turnjs.com/) div
need to flip pages and go to specific page

Comment: You want to embed Adobe Reader inside a div?

Answer (score 28):

```
<div>
<object data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
alt : <a href="test.pdf">test.pdf</a>
</object>
</div>
```

Read this thread - http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?152923-PDF-within-a-DIV

Comment: ya its cool man but i want this in side Turnjs div,how can i implement with turnjs? separate pages in separate div

Comment: please check these link 1:https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/issues/89   2:http://www.maxims6n.bget.ru/pdf_books/demo_21.html

Answer (score 10):

You can use this code:

```
<embed src="http://domain.com/your_pdf.pdf" width="600" height="500" alt="pdf" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html">
```

Or use Google Docs embeddable PDF viewer:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://domain.com/your_pdf.pdf&embedded=true" 
style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: <embed /> works fine in desktop browsers but not in mobile... how to make it working in mobile browsers?

Answer (score 5):

Dare I speak it's name for fear of being castigated, but you could use an iframe and allow the browser to provide the navigation.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is drag the pdf to google drive. Then, click on the new pdf (it will usually be upper left in google drive), click the share icon at the top, go to **advanced**, then click **change** and make sure the "Public" radio button is clicked. Click **SAVE**, then click **DONE**.
Now go back to google drive, click on the pdf to open it, then click the Pop-out icon (upper right, next to the X close icon). Once the pdf is now full screen, click the : more actions icon (three vertical dots) There you will find an "Embed" opportunity. Click that and you get the embed code.  Voila!!

Note: The pdf gotten this way will be ready to paste into your blog or HTML website, AND any links in the document will work!! AND, there will be a little Pop-out icon in the upper right, upon hover, that makes the pdf full screen. And, you can pop it into a **div** if you want to put more than one on the page. Some examples are up at [http://internetpdf.com](http://www.internetpdf.com).

John Burch

Comment: I think this should be comment