# Show Pdf in MVC html view not working

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I am working to show in my view a PDF that comes as a URL. To do that I am using [object tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084148/how-to-display-pdf-content-in-web-page-using-html5-and-jquery). But my problem is that the PDF does not show.

This is my code, to start I hardcoded to test the behaviour in my view:

```
form id="EditRecurso" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix the following errors.")
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Titulo)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Titulo, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Titulo)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Descripcion)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.Descripcion, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Descripcion)
    </div>
   //show here the pdf -->
<object data="https://www.salisbury.edu/helpdesk/doc/Computer/Operating_System_Bios_Boot/OS_Windows7ProductGuide.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="600" height="300"></object>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Url)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Url, new { type = "file", name = "miRecurso" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Url)
    </div>
    <button id="submiter" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Listo!</button>
</div>
```

And the result in my MVC view is this:

[PDF not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQSBA.png)
As you can see it never shows the PDF. But the object tag is there.

On the other hand, when I use plain HTML with the same object tag to link a PDF, this is the result:

[PDF displayed in html document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM6gr.png)

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<object data="https://www.salisbury.edu/helpdesk/doc/Computer/Operating_System_Bios_Boot/OS_Windows7ProductGuide.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="600" height="300"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

Any Idea what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code and it worked for me in chrome. Do you have some CSS which is placing the object out of visibility ?

Comment: Your code works in Firefox 54 & Chrome 60 - do you missing some important objects which not included in this question?