# Embedding: ViewLinkRequest.ReturnUrl doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, .net-core, docusignapi

I'm using [docusign-csharp-client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client) and following code snippet to receive the view url for **completed** envelope, and suppose to be redirected to `returnUrl` once close action would be performed by the user, who consumes the generated link.

```
var link = _envelopesApi.CreateViewLink(accountId, envelopeId, new ViewLinkRequest { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, Email = consumerEmail });
```

As a result user receives an envelope view, but after closing it she gets redirected on my docusing account home page instead of expected `returnUrl`.

Is there any straightforward way to achieve what I need in Embedded Workflows?

1. Display the completed document
2. Redirect consuming user to my return url

It's demo account.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [embedded recipient view](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/). It can be used even after the recipient has viewed.

Or an easier answer is to fetch the documents from DocuSigh to your server and then show them to your users as appropriate.

The ViewLink method doesn't do what you want and is deprecated.

Comment: Actually recipient view has the same flaw - signer, who has already signed, gets redirected in wrong destination by clicking "Close" when she doesn't need to sign anymore.

Comment: An approach with download back to client system doesn't look too seamless as well - it creates the bad UX, i.e. initial view has DocuSign experince, then we need to implement own viewer and it would be another experience. Definitely there are workarounds anyway, but just wondering why so bad UX in those cases which look pretty easy to implement.

Comment: It is not hard to show a pdf on the page see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084148/how-to-display-pdf-content-in-web-page-using-html5-and-jquery  You could show it in a modal as gmail does. (Click on the icon of a pdf attached to an email msg, not the download link of the icon)